# pandas vs numpy packages in python

Tags: python-3.x

Are pandas iterrows fast compare to np.where on a smaller dataset? I heard numpy is always efficient compared to pandas?

I was surprised to see that when I used iterrow in my code vs numpy's np.where on a small dataset, iterrows execution was fast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a speed difference.

Feel free to post your `timeit` benchmark figures.